# Hash mysql password with something stronger than md5

Tags: mysql, encryption, md5

I set my password to use md5 and as a test I put the password as owner. I then went to [this website](http://www.hashkiller.co.uk/md5-decrypter.aspx)
and put the md5 hash down and it was able to give me back the password. I don't feel as if md5 is secure. Any ideas on how to make the hash function stronger?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practice for storing usernames & password in MySQL Databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397276/best-practice-for-storing-usernames-password-in-mysql-databases)

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235158/sha1-vs-md5-vs-sha256-which-to-use-for-a-php-login

Comment: What language is your program in?  I'd let that handle the password *hashing* instead of MySQL.

Comment: @RocketHazmat html/php

Comment: If you're using PHP, then I suggest you use http://php.net/password_hash and http://php.net/password_verify for your passwords.

Comment: Follow the advice given in the [password hashing guide](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing). MD5 is completely useless for storing passwords, it can be cracked too easily.  Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) built-in.

Comment: MD5 is a hash function, not an encryption algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up salting the passwords with password_hash and password_verify

Answer (score -2):

Use the MYSQL SHA1() hash function.

The guys commenting my answer and downvoting are right. Although it says in the MYSQL manual:

"You can also use SHA1() as a cryptographic function for storing passwords.",

fine print tells another story...

Comment: Has the same problem with rainbow tables

Comment: Don't use MySQL to handle passwords.  You want your application to do that.